# Push button counting

Tags: led, atmel, avr-gcc

I'm trying to have a button iterate a LED strip through binary. Each press would either increment +1 or -1 depending on the button. However, My code doesn't seem to store the variable in the do-while loop. The LEDs that light up are random on each button press.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

void main(void) {
  //declare DDRx
  DDRD = 0b11111100;  //set PD2-PD7 to output
  DDRB = 0b00000011; //set PB0-PB1 to output and rest to input
  PORTB = 0b00001100; // set internal pullups in PB2 and PB3 turn PB0 and PB1 off
  PORTD = 0b00000000; //turn off PORTD
  //declare num counter
 int num = 0;

  do {

    if ((PINB & 0b0000100) == 0) { //check if PB2 is pressed
      num++;  //add 1 to n i.e. n = 1 on first loop
      PORTD &= 0b0000011; //clear bits 7 - 2
      PORTD |= (num << 2);  //shift bits

      PORTB &= 0b11111100; //clear bits 1 - 0
      PORTB |= (num >> 6);  //shit bits
    } else if ((PINB & 0b0001000) == 0) { //check if PB3 is pressed
      num--; //minus 1 to n
      PORTD &= 0b00000011; //clear bits
      PORTD |= (num << 2); //shift bits

      PORTB &= 0b11111100;
      PORTB |= (num >> 6);
    }
  } while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is strictly a programming question, and is off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: I designed/built this 40 yrs ago with an LED calculator and interfaced to the = sign after it was externally sequenced with CLR, 1,+ but I used 1" LED 7 seg external driver and display with a $10 calculator.

Answer (score 5):

You need to be aware that as written your code will spin around the while loop dozens if not 100's of times seeing the one or the other of the switches pressed. Since your IF statement only checks for the '0' level of the switch input it will detect for as long as the input is active.

So you will need to change your coding strategy some. Each time around the WHILE loop you need to look for the 1 -> 0 transition of the switch input. This can be done by keeping the input value from the previous transit of the loop in a history variable. The the detect logic become:
    If previous bit == 1 and current bit == 0 Then Detect active.

You should become familiar with switch bounce. You will most likely also need to implement switch bounce filtering in the software unless you have taken steps in the hardware part of the design to assure no bounce signals get to the MCU pin.